# Google Earth Engine goes unresponsive during large extraction

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

**What we are trying to do:**

We are trying to extract a NDVI time series for a large dataset of insect outbreaks. This time series needs to be associated with the observation date for each insect outbreak point. So for a buffered area around each point, we would like to go back at least 30 days prior to outbreak observation and gather all sentinel available images, calculate NDVI and eventually put this into one large CSV with two columns: NDVI and days before observation.

**How we are doing it:**

The incomplete script below makes two arrays, one containing NDVI values, the other containing unix time stamps for 50 randomly sample outbreak points. So for instance the third value listed in the NDVI array corresponds to the third date in the date array. Each array should have three to four values because that is about how often sentinel passes overhead in 30 days.

**What the problem is:**

GEE is becoming unresponsive to getInfo() calls after about 50-100 cells. We think this is google deliberately denying the request.

Initially, we ran 500 randomly sampled entries and would make one request at the end, however that script would freeze up. Next, we tried requesting each row individually and storing them on my end in a csv (this is shown in the code below) which we have had more luck with, however it still seems that after about 70 entries google no longer responds to getInfo() requests.

Any idea on how to keep GEE from going unresponsive?

We tried to sleep the loop incase we were hitting [google API rate limits](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas), however that doesnt seem to fix it

Check below for the batch process attempt. This code works with a data frame with < 500 observations. However it times out when I give it the entire dataset it times out.

```
#############################NDVI at locations##################

import ee
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ee.Authenticate()

ee.Initialize()
l8 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")

table = ee.FeatureCollection([
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([73.13138889,26.53944444]),{"system:index":"0"}).set('dateUnix',1531717200000),
ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([73.24555556,27.19666667]),{"system:index":"1"}).set('dateUnix',1550728800000)])

NDVIvalues = np.array([None]*40)
Timevalues = np.array([None]*40)

lat = [26.53944444 ,
27.19666667 ,
25.70777778 ,
25.91138889 ,
14.28527778 ,
25.66694444 ,
15.20722222 ,
22.42694444 ,
25.78833333 ,
25.72555556 ,
27.47083333 ,
14.78083333 ,
25.69888889 ,
27.14805556 ,
17.96972222 ,
27.30666667 ,
27.99972222 ,
27.9925 ,
16.31777778 ,
27.00027778 ,
13.25027778 ,
25.44638889 ,
27.64027778 ,
16.50416667 ,
28.79222222 ,
27.0575 ,
28.32527778 ,
24.17444444 ,
19.78 ,
27.13111111 ,
20.60055556 ,
25.95 ,
14.98333333 ,
18.16444444 ,
18.925 ,
27.91416667 ,
27.31777778 ,
27.29527778 ,
18.83277778 ,
25.17833333 ]

longitude = [73.13138889 ,
73.24555556 ,
66.2475 ,
58.10222222 ,
22.39972222 ,
66.59694444 ,
36.82027778 ,
31.64277778 ,
59.31166667 ,
66.62555556 ,
72.13416667 ,
30.35833333 ,
66.69666667 ,
68.78138889 ,
41.71083333 ,
41.31444444 ,
72.42277778 ,
72.57833333 ,
22.39277778 ,
68.82666667 ,
19.84472222 ,
59.5125 ,
71.35444444 ,
48.84083333 ,
72.30611111 ,
71.15555556 ,
72.43166667 ,
35.33555556 ,
37.14944444 ,
72.01361111 ,
35.83305556 ,
72.92916667 ,
-10.9 ,
38.12555556 ,
35.5775 ,
70.84361111 ,
73.90166667 ,
72.49388889 ,
50.05555556 ,
70.88555556]

times = [1531717200000 ,
1550728800000 ,
1560315600000 ,
1561352400000 ,
1568955600000 ,
1492578000000 ,
1531544400000 ,
1543298400000 ,
1560747600000 ,
1525928400000 ,
1543557600000 ,
1496811600000 ,
1505019600000 ,
1535950800000 ,
1575871200000 ,
1556427600000 ,
1570597200000 ,
1573797600000 ,
1565845200000 ,
1529902800000 ,
1574056800000 ,
1574056800000 ,
1567573200000 ,
1503118800000 ,
1533790800000 ,
1502686800000 ,
1510120800000 ,
1577080800000 ,
1513576800000 ,
1569560400000 ,
1576303200000 ,
1519279200000 ,
1545976800000 ,
1520056800000 ,
1533704400000 ,
1499576400000 ,
1539234000000 ,
1529298000000 ,
1547704800000 ,
1531976400000 ]

latf = None
longf = None
timef = None


def locational(lat,longi,time):

  feature = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([longi,lat]),{"system:index":"0"}).set('dateUnix',time)

  end = ee.Number(feature.get('dateUnix'))
  start = end.subtract(2592000000)

  #start = ee.Date(1496793600000)
  #end = ee.Date(1528329600000)

  #end = ee.Date('2019-06-01')
  #start = ee.Date('2019-05-01')
  
  ########define date range of interest
  
  fCollectp = l8.filterBounds(feature.geometry())
  fCollect = fCollectp.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end))
  #filterdate range
  buffed = feature.geometry().buffer(1000)
  

  def addDates(image):
    imagep = ee.Image(image)

    setted = None

            
    nir = imagep.select('B5');
    red = imagep.select('B4');
    ndviImage = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');
    NDVIavgp = ndviImage.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),buffed,scale=30,maxPixels=1e9)
    NDVIavg = NDVIavgp.get('NDVI')
    NDVIdateCap = ee.String(image.get('GENERATION_TIME'))

    tempA = ee.List([NDVIavg,-9999])
    tempB = tempA.reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())#this will filter out a null if the image was not actually over the gauge
    


    NDVISetted = ee.Image(image.set('date',NDVIdateCap).set('NDVI',tempB))


    return NDVISetted
      
  mapC = fCollect.map(addDates)
  agg = mapC.aggregate_array('date')
  aggb = mapC.aggregate_array('NDVI')
  agFeat = feature.set('dates',agg).set('NDVI', aggb)
  return agFeat.getInfo()


for x in range(40):
    latf = lat[x]
    longf = longitude[x]
    timef = times[x]

    result = locational(latf,longf,timef)
    properties = result.get('properties')
    ttt = properties.get('dates')
    nnn = properties.get('NDVI')
    NDVIvalues[x] = nnn
    Timevalues[x] = ttt
    print(x)
print(NDVIvalues)
print(Timevalues)
df = pd.DataFrame(NDVIvalues)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Timevalues)
#df.to_csv('file.csv',index=False)
```

The batch attempt can be seen below:

```
########################################################################################
#############################NDVI at locations----OLD VERSION ##########################

import ee
ee.Initialize()
l8 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")

table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/ddlawton/Locust_dat_Jan_22_2")


#table = ee.FeatureCollection([
#ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-69.7155556,46.70055556]),{"system:index":"0"}).set('dateUnix',1548136800000),
#ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-69.0880556,47.11305556]),{"system:index":"1"}).set('dateUnix',1548136800000),
#ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-69.0794444,47.0697222]),{"system:index":"2"}).set('dateUnix',1548136800000),
#ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-68.3716667,46.52305556]),{"system:index":"3"}).set('dateUnix',1548136800000),])



def locational(feature):

  end = ee.Number(feature.get('unixdates'))
  start = end.subtract(2592000000) #subtract 30 days (in milliseconds)

  #start = ee.Date(1496793600000)
  #end = ee.Date(1528329600000)

  #end = ee.Date('2019-06-01')
  #start = ee.Date('2019-05-01')
  
  ########define date range of interest
  
  fCollectp = l8.filterBounds(feature.geometry().buffer(500))
  fCollect = fCollectp.filter(ee.Filter.date(start, end))
  #filterdate range
  buffed = feature.geometry().buffer(500)
  

  def addDates(image):
    imagep = ee.Image(image)
    setted = None
    nir = imagep.select('B5');
    red = imagep.select('B4');
    ndviImage = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');
    NDVIavgp = ndviImage.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(),buffed,scale=30,maxPixels=1e9)
    NDVIavg = NDVIavgp.get('NDVI')
    NDVIdateCap = ee.String(image.get('GENERATION_TIME'))

    tempA = ee.List([NDVIavg,-9999])
    tempB = tempA.reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())#this will filter out a null if the image was not actually over the gauge
    


    NDVISetted = ee.Image(image.set('date',NDVIdateCap).set('NDVI',tempB))


    return NDVISetted
      
  mapC = fCollect.map(addDates)
  agg = mapC.aggregate_array('date')
  aggb = mapC.aggregate_array('NDVI')
  agFeat = feature.set('dates',agg).set('NDVI', aggb)
  return agFeat

mapF = table.map(locational)
agg2 = mapF.aggregate_array('dates').getInfo()
agg3 = mapF.aggregate_array('NDVI').getInfo()

task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(
  collection=mapF,
  description='ROTLpyTest',
  fileFormat='CSV'
)

task.start()
```

However in this attempt, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/envs/Clumped_GEE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ee/data.py in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    333   try:
--> 334     return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    335   except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Clumped_GEE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    133                     logger.warning(message)
--> 134             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    135 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Clumped_GEE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    914         if resp.status >= 300:
--> 915             raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    916         return self.postproc(resp, content)

HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/value:compute?prettyPrint=false&alt=json returned "Computation timed out.". Details: "Computation timed out.">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

EEException                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-a7fd4fba168e> in <module>
     63 
     64 mapF = table.map(locational)
---> 65 agg2 = mapF.aggregate_array('dates').getInfo()
     66 agg3 = mapF.aggregate_array('NDVI').getInfo()
     67 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Clumped_GEE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ee/computedobject.py in getInfo(self)
     93       The object can evaluate to anything.
     94     """
---> 95     return data.computeValue(self)
     96 
     97   def encode(self, encoder):

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Clumped_GEE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ee/data.py in computeValue(obj)
    672     The result of evaluating that object on the server.
    673   """
--> 674   return _execute_cloud_call(
    675       _get_cloud_api_resource().projects().value().compute(
    676           body={'expression': serializer.encode(obj, for_cloud_api=True)},

/opt/anaconda3/envs/Clumped_GEE/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ee/data.py in _execute_cloud_call(call, num_retries)
    334     return call.execute(num_retries=num_retries)
    335   except googleapiclient.errors.HttpError as e:
--> 336     raise _translate_cloud_exception(e)
    337 
    338 

EEException: Computation timed out.
```

This does not happen when you give GEE < 500 observations.

Comment: For big requests use `batch.Export.to...`. `getInfo()` is not made for that.

Comment: Also try to use `.map` instead of for loops. I am not too sure if this is also applicable to the Python client but in the Javascript client, the performance of for loops is very bad.

Comment: Good point @JonasV! The batch process we used uses the .map function. I have attached the additional code and error. Any idea why it times out after 500?